# Mysql only showing rows with 2 or more values in a column

Tags: mysql

I have a query results that is similar to the following:

| Part ID | Company |
| --- | --- |
| 102 | ABC Corp |
| 102 | XYZ Corp |
| 103 | ABC Corp |
| 104 | EFG Corp |
| 104 | HIJ Corp |

This table is created with a simple query such as `SELECT part_id, company FROM MyTable`

However, I only want to return rows where the part ID number occurs more than once, i.e. I want the '103' part ID row taken out, as it has only one listing.

I tried using `COUNT(*)` but this returns '1' as the rows are always going to be unique. I want to remove rows where the COUNT of the total occurrences of a Part ID is only 1.

Comment: have you tried group by with having count clause ?

Comment: i've tried HAVING COUNT(part_id) > 1 but that for some reason returns 0 results.

Comment: please share sample data and the query used by you.

Comment: Please show the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from
(SELECT part_id, company, count(pard_id) as count
FROM MyTable group by part_id,company) as a
where a.count>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT part_id, company
FROM   mytable
WHERE  part_id IN (SELECT part_id
                   FROM   mytable
                   GROUP  BY part_id
                   HAVING Count(*) > 1)
```

Output will be

```
Part ID Company
102 ABC Corp
102 XYZ Corp
104 EFG Corp
104 HIJ Corp
```